# questions about properties of half-open rectangles

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis

A half-open rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of the form:$P=(a_1,b_1] \times \cdots \times (a_n,b_n]$ with $a_{i} <b_{i}$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$.

My questions are :

1. Is the union of half-open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^n$ still a half-open rectangle? That is, if $P_1,\ldots,P_k$ are half-open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is it true that $P_{1} \cup \cdots \cup P_{k}$ is a half-open rectangle?
2. If P is a half-open rectangle, is the closure of P still a half-open rectangle?

Since in one dimension, the closure of a half-open interval $(a,b]$ is $[a,b]$, i guess the answer to the second question is no. However, how do i justify the first question?

Comment: Two half-open rectangles need not be adjacent.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: In $\Bbb R^2$, Is the union of half-open rectangles $(0,1]\times (0,1]$ and $(1,2]\times (1,2]$ a  half-open rectangle? What is the closure of  the half-open rectangle $(0,1]\times (0,1]$?